# Why is けしゴム (eraser) half written in hiragana and half in katakana?

Tags: words, katakana, hiragana

Why is the word *けしゴム* is half written in *hiragana* and half in *katakana*?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It just has to do with the words that it is made up of:

消し｛けし｝ comes from 消す｛けす｝which means *to erase*.

ゴム is [a foreign word](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%B4%E3%83%A0) (usually katakana) meaning gum or rubber.

So you put the two together and you get the amalgam 消し｛けし｝ゴム.

Comment: Did you invent a new word to make a pun? (*amal**gum***)

Comment: @Earthliŋ Teehee, I wish.  I actually thought that was how it was spelled :P

Comment: what were you trying to say? amalgamation? amalgam = a mash-up of metals > https://www.google.co.jp/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=amalgam

Comment: @Mark これだったかな?w　http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/amalgam

Comment: A more technical term might be [hybrid word](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_word). In general, I think it should be a [compound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_(linguistics)).

Comment: Haha, good to know! Did you want me to change it?

Answer (score 1):

Because けし comes from the verb and ゴム in itself is a loanword.

Comment: Maybe you could say that "the verb" is 消す.